# I am trying to download multiple image as a zip file but getting error using laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to download multiple images as a zip file but getting errors
**Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** please help me how i resolve that thanks.
[image]

Check the error: https://flareapp.io/share/47qG2A3m

##### Controller

```
public function dowloads($id)
{
    $url = config('yourstitchart.file_url');
    
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $inboxFiles = Inbox::where('id', $id)->first()->file;

    // $inboxFiles = "["phpCM0Yia.png","phptLC57a.png"]"

    foreach ($inboxFiles as $file) {
        $zip->add($url . $file); // update it by your path
    }
    $zip->close();
    
    return response()
        ->download(
            public_path('/temporary_files/' . "deals.zip"),
            "deals.zip",
            ["Content-Type" => "application/zip"]
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a string, you can't handle it like an array.

It's JSON, you can just use :

```
$inboxFiles = json_decode(Inbox::where('id', $id)->first()->file);
```

(the above code is not really robust, but you have the way)

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, but do not use `json_decode` any more in Laravel...

[Cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) the field `file` as a `JSON`/`array`, so it will automatically be an array and when you save it in the database, it will be transformed to JSON, and when you want to read it back, it will be automatically transformed to array...

To do so, you have to edit `Inbox` model and add this property:

```
protected $casts = ['file' => 'array'];
```

And that's it, then you have to use the field as if it is already an array, so leaving your code as it is in your question, without any edit, it will work right away:

```php
public function dowloads($id)
{
    $url = config('yourstitchart.file_url');
    
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $inboxFiles = Inbox::where('id', $id)->first()->file;

    // $inboxFiles = "["phpCM0Yia.png","phptLC57a.png"]"

    foreach ($inboxFiles as $file) {
        $zip->add($url . $file); // update it by your path
    }
    $zip->close();
    
    return response()
        ->download(
            public_path('/temporary_files/' . "deals.zip"),
            "deals.zip",
            ["Content-Type" => "application/zip"]
        );
}
```